# What really happen when I compile int main; in C

Tags: c, codeblocks

What really happen when I compile:

```
int main;
```

Isn't it supposed to be main() and caused an error ?

I tried to compile the code in CodeBlocks and it compiled perfectly without error.

Comment: Doesn't it simply declare an integer called `main`?

Comment: @Rob However, when I tried to run " int x; "

CodeBlocks gives me this error : undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Comment: You can definitely have your program running with it, though some compilers will throw a warning if you declare a variable called `main` : `warning: 'main' is usually a function`

Comment: It's about scope. It's fine to share a name among entites for the compiler, though it's a bad habit to do so, getting code too messy.

Comment: So finally, what is your question? In your topic you were asking what happens if you use this line : `int main;`, saying that you can run your program with no error. Later in your comment, you just said you have this error : `undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'`. Do you still have to solve it?

Comment: @Rob 

No, I still haven't solve it. I was trying to say that since you said I simply declare an integer called `main`, why do CodeBlocks allowed to run with no error ? On the other hand, when I tried to run `int x;`, I had `the undefined reference to WinMain@16 ` error.

Comment: @ThanakronTandavas: the reason's in the answer below... if you don't declare `main` at all, the linker will give an error.

Comment: I think in the above you mean 'compiles' without error; not 'runs' without error.

Comment: @teppic Thank you for pointing that out. I meant " compile " not " run". Sorry for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not an error as a C source file doesn't need to have a `main` function and you can define `main` as whatever you want as long as you don't try to define it twice in the same scope. As this is your whole program, it's fine - but the program certainly won't run correctly as there is no `main` function to find.

All it does is declare a global (external) variable called main, initialised to 0. The linker would normally issue an error if it's not there, but it may be satisfied with presence of the external variable (I expect it's assuming it's a pointer).

EDIT: I looked into this a little with the debugger, and sure enough, `main` has a value of 0, i.e. the variable is being used as a pointer without a cast. So the initialisation code tries to run a function located at address 0, resulting in a segfault on my platform.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting confused here due to incorrect (or lack of understand) of the scope.

When you say here a declaration of `int main;` is being passed by the compiler, I am assuming you are declaring it within a function scope. But, if you try declaring it in global scope, then the compiler will throw an redefinition error.

So, as long as you don't have two identical identifiers within the same scope, compiler will be satisfied and will let you have your way.

The below code will give redeinition error:

```
int main;

int main()
{
  printf("In main\n");
}
```

The below code won't because the scope of main is restricted inside the function only and compiler considers the `int main` variable and result is printed out as 5.

```
int main()
{ 
   int main = 5;
   printf("In main, value of main is %d\n", main);
}
```

The below code however will print the address of main

```
int main()
{
       printf("In main, value of main is %d\n", main);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
After reading through the comments, I feel the key problem here is that you are not having a main function at all, which you should have for a "C" program to start working. If you don't have a main function, but just declare an `int main;` variable, your code might still compile, but when you execute there will be confusion and chaos as main is an integer variable, whereas it is expected to be a function. But, as long as you keep your main(s) under control as per my above answer, you should do fine.

You can go [this](http://decodingtech.com/process-of-compilation-and-execution-of-c-program/) link, which explains the concept of compilation and execution of a C program

Comment: From the comments, that's the whole program, i.e. there is no main function.